# Как добавить время с часовым поясом в базу Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

Создаю вот такую таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mailing_tasks (
    user_base_from TEXT,
    time TIME WITH TIME ZONE
);
```

Как мне добавить в time например вот такое время **04:05:06 -8:00**?

Пробовал вот так, но выдает ошибку: (код на Python)

```
async def add_message_for_mailing(self, user_base, time) -> None:
    await self.conn.execute(
        "INSERT INTO mailing_tasks (user_base_from, time) VALUES ($1,$2)",
        user_base, time
    )
    return
```

```
await repo.add('base', '04:05:06 -8:00')
```

**asyncpg.exceptions.DataError: invalid input for query argument $2: '04:05:06 -8:00' ('str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo')**

Comment: Судя по тексту ошибки — используйте объект time вместо строки? `datetime.time(4, 5, 6, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(offset=datetime.timedelta(hours=-8)))`

Comment: @andreymal я не совсем в этом разбираюсь, но у меня пользователь бота должен ввести время и часовой пояс, а я затем эту строку должен впихнуть в БД.
Есть способ это сделать?

Comment: Если вам нужно впихнуть именно **строку** — значит вместо типа `TIME WITH TIME ZONE` используйте CHAR / VARCHAR / TEXT. Если же вам всё-таки нужно время — значит преобразуйте строку в объект time